# Can I connect  to a remote mysql instance without installing mysql locally?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a remote server's mysql instance from PHP on my main server.

The main server itself has no mysql installed but the server I'm trying to connect to has mysql installed.

PHP is installed on both servers but I was wondering if it would connect when mysql isn't installed locally.

Comment: What OS/PHP install is on the main server? Rather platform specific what's enabled or not by default.

Answer (score 2):

You only need a client mysql library specific to your database connection stack, not a mysql server installation.

Comment: Does it need much ram usage ? cus mysql server needs about 300 / 500 MB, and what's the command for installing it ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that I can see for it not working. Keep in mind that you'll need the hostname of the server and the server will have to have remote_access configured.

Comment: yup i have the hostname and remote access is enabled, but i don't get results in back

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to have the second server's URL and SQL info such as username and password.
no reason for it not to work.